# check query string under if condition using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, query-string

hey i want to check type of query string in if condition what is the right way to do this pls help . . my url is something like this . .

```
http://localhost/kccs/index.php/dbcont/addnew?type=moderator
http://localhost/kccs/index.php/dbcont/addnew?type=member
```

i want to check

```
if(query string type==moderator)
{
   //some stuff
}
if(query string type==member)
{
  //some stuff
}
```

i want to enable query string only two pages
i find this on another link

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$_GET);
```

but i didnot know how to use it..
how could i do this . . any idea pls help me . .

Comment: Why don't you try `$_GET['type']` ?

Comment: i get error by this `A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: type

Filename: controllers/dbcont.php

Line Number: 41` @DaHaKa

Comment: @DaHaKa  is any other way to resolve this error . .

Comment: When you are accessing for example in `index.php?type=moderator` , in `index.php` file if you write `$_GET['type']` you will receive `moderator` as a result . From you error its seems you have file replacement problems, in that case I can't help because don't know codeigniter

Comment: its ok thanks for try for me . . @DaHaKa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$this->input->get('some_variable', TRUE);
```

[see more info](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html)

Comment: :- its work for other functions but not in my desired function..i dont know why its not work in a perticular function..thanx for help

Answer (score 0):

You should check [GET](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp) variable. Code sample using if's:

```
if ($_GET['type'] == 'moderator') {
  //do something
} elseif ($_GET['type'] == 'member') {
  //do something else
}
```

Alternatively you could use [switch()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php):

```
switch($_GET['type']) {
  case 'moderator':
    //do something
    break;
  case 'member':
    //do something else
    break;
  default: //else
    //you're a guest
    break;
}
```

Comment: i got tis error `A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: type

Filename: controllers/dbcont.php

Line Number: 41`  @Tom

Comment: Oh, you're running Codeigniter. @rahul-chipad wrote how you should get variables from URL. In your case, it would be $this->input->get('type', true). Try echoing it to see if it works.

Comment: :- ya its work when echo but not work when use in if condition for condition checking . . .